# Объединить 2 массива структур и удалить дубликаты в Go

Tags: массивы, json, golang

Имею 2 массива структурированных данных, десериализовав JSON-ответ от сервера в массив структур:

```
type SectionsList struct {
    Id          string `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Photo       string `json:"photo"`
}
```

Нужно объединить их и удалить дубликаты по Id. Собственно, как с этим работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через хэш-таблицы, например.

```
m := make(map[string]T, len(ts1) + len(ts2))
for _, t := range ts1 {
    m[t.ID] = t
}
for _, t := range ts2 {
    m[t.ID] = t
}

ts0 := make([]T, 0, len(m))
for _, t := range m {
    ts0 = append(ts0, t)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-rbrp_xZ2H.

Кстати, по [стайлгайду](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms), ваш `Id` должен называться `ID`.

Comment: Спасибо)) наверно буду лучше сразу десериализовывать в мапу.